# How to turn on fingerprint login in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: login, lenovo

I've got lenovo YOGA s730 with Ubuntu 20.04 and can't turn on fingerprint login. In other questions on forum people have troubles with turning on fingerprint in settings > users > authentication and login, but I don't even have a button there, which is strange, since there should be built-in feature in 20.04, right?

Answer (score 1):

The Yoga 730 uses a "special" Synaptics fingerprint reader that does not work out of the box with either `fprint` or `thinkfinger`. There is [a prototype driver](https://github.com/nmikhailov/Validity90) being built by some talented people, but it's not 100% solid just yet.

For the moment the fingerprint reader on your Lenovo will likely sit idle. Hopefully there will be a compatible driver available by the time the next LTS rolls around.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score -1):

How to install fingerprint driver on Lenovo Yoga 730 running Ubuntu?
The fingerprint driver for Lenovo Yoga 730 running Ubuntu can be installed by following these steps:

1. Open the terminal and run the commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fprintd libpam-fprintd
sudo pam-auth-update
```

2. In the PAM configuration menu, select `Fingerprint authentication` and click OK.
3. Finally, restart your system and the fingerprint driver should be installed and working.

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: So you're saying fprintd supports this reader now, unlike the existing answer? Which version of Ubuntu did you test it on? Kernel version? fprintd version?